# Can't get the id from $routeParams.id

Tags: angularjs

When i console.log $routeParams, i get an object contains the id, but when i address the id key by doing $routeParams.id - i get undefined. I've found some related answers - but for some reason nothing seems to work...

Here is the component where i console.log the id

```
var app = angular.module('blogList').component('blogList', {
    template: '<div>' + '{{title}}' +
                  '<button ng-click="someFunc()">Click</button>' +
                  '<ul ng-if="items.length > 0">' +
                      '<li ng-repeat="item in items"><a ng-href="{{item.id}}">  {{ item.title }} < /a></li > '+
                  '</ul>' +
              '</div>',
    controller: function($routeParams, $scope) {
        console.log($routeParams.id); // Undefiend
        var blogItems = [
            { title: "home", id: 1, link: "home" },
            { title: "about", id: 2, link: "about" },
            { title: "contact", id: 3, link: "contact" }
        ];
        $scope.items = blogItems;
        $scope.title = 'Clicked ';
        $scope.clicks = 0;
        $scope.someFunc = function() {
            $scope.clicks += 1;
            $scope.title = 'Clicked ' + $scope.clicks + 'times';
        }
    }
});
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/5MBxU6pD6QkW48ZoclGC?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)...

> ...the `$routeParams` are only updated after a route change completes successfully. This means that you cannot rely on `$routeParams` being correct in route resolve functions. Instead you can use `$route.current.params` to access the new route's parameters.

You should use `$route` instead and get the id as

```
console.log($route.current.params.id);
```

Comment: thanks - I've tried it - but i still get undefined...can't figure it out...

Comment: Are you [injecting](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) `$route` into your controller?

Comment: yeah - app.controller('foo', ['$scope','$route', function ($scope,$route)
{
    $scope.model = {
        id: angular.fromJson($route.current.params.id)
    }
}]);

Comment: The contents of `$route.current.params.id` is definitely not JSON. Why `fromJson()`? `console.log($route)`. What are you getting? If nothing, it's something else, so your question is currently incomplete.

Comment: @RoyBarOn, I took a look at your Plunker. Before you can request a `$route` param you need add it in, inside the route config function. Please take a look at [$route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route) and how routes are configured in `script.js` (`bookId` param) in their example. You need to do the same in `app.config.js`. Right now your `$route`s do not have an `id` param.